# How to extract decimal part of datenum of Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, datetime

I have got the following code in matlab.

```
timestamp = 1478084255 ;
TimeZone = 'Europe/Amsterdam' ;
CorrectionToMATLABTime = datenum(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0,0) ;

matlab_timestamp = CorrectionToMATLABTime + timestamp/86400 ;
d = datetime( datevec(matlab_timestamp), 'TimeZone', 'UTC' );
d.TimeZone = TimeZone ; 
datenum(d)

# 736636.498321759
```

What would be the equilvent code in **python** to get decimal part of the datenum i.e 0.498321759 ?

Here is what I have done :

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')
date_utc = datetime.fromtimestamp(1478084255).astimezone(tz)
first_date = datetime(date.year, 1, 1, tzinfo=tz)
(date_utc - first_date).seconds/(60*60*24)
# 0.45665509259259257
```

Comment: How about `dn = datenum(d); decimalpart = dn - floor(dn);`?

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question in exact terms:

```
import datetime
import pytz
tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')
d = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1478084255).replace(tzinfo = pytz.utc)
d = d.astimezone(tz).replace(tzinfo = pytz.utc)
f = datetime.datetime.combine(d.date(), datetime.time()).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
(d-f).total_seconds() / (60* 60* 24) # 0.498321759
```

Having said that, I think what you're calculating is not what you think you're calculating. It seems that matlab's datenum ignores the 'timezone' portion of the `datetime` object entirely, which I suspect may not be what you intended. You can check the above is the case by confirming that `datenum(d)` gives the same result as `datenum(datevec(d))`.

Perhaps it would be worth asking explicitly what it is you're **expecting** to get out of this calculation in words as well, just to check it really does correspond to the code you've provided. What are you trying to do exactly?